# Ctrl + click not work on Visual Studio code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have VS code, and I want to navigate between file used on namespace, but always I get this error.

> Unable to open 'Template.php': File not found
>   (file:///c:/wamp64/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php)

And my folder is a shared folder opened from `F:` not `C:` and not found on `wamp64/www/` directories

After some modification and tries, now the `CTRL + CLICK` not working definitely on VS code and `F12` to.

Is there any solution ?